# How to create TCL or perl script which can count total number of bits and if there is a mismatch then script should add 0 for remaining bits

Tags: regex, perl, tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to create one TCL or perl script which will compare number and total number of bit count and if there is mismatch then place 0's in the beginning:
Partial contents of the file:

```
// DEBUG: TDO     : 16'b1
// DEBUG: STEP #  : 3
// DEBUG: TDI     : 35'b1011101001011110100000100100100
// DEBUG: TDO     : 35'b0xx001011101001011110100000100100100
// DEBUG: LOAD_DR ( 35 , 35'b1011101001011110100000100100100 ) ;
// DEBUG: STEP  #  : 4
// DEBUG: LOAD_NOP ( 2 ) ;
// DEBUG: STEP #  : 5
// DEBUG: TDI     : 8'b1011101001011110100000100100101
// DEBUG: TDO     : 8'b100
// DEBUG: LOAD_DR ( 35 , 35'b1011101001011110100000100100101 ) ;
```

Here, for some TDO , bits are incomplete.
For ex.:
 8'b100, here there are only 3 bits but number is 8 so wherever this kind of scenario is there I need to place extra 0's at the beginning for remaining bits.For 8'b100 output should be 8'b**00000**100 and this script should replace this bit in the original file without affecting any other contents of the file:

Partial contents of Expected output for 8'b100 after making required changes by the script

```
// DEBUG: STEP #  : 5
// DEBUG: TDI     : 8'b1011101001011110100000100100101
// DEBUG: TDO     : 8'b00000100
```

TCL script is preferable but Perl is also fine.

Comment: Hi @DaveCross, I am in very initial phase of TCL/perl scripting so that is why I need help to create this script. Please help me if you have any idea. I will really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Why are there "x" characters in the 2nd TDO line?

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. Your account activity shows a history of questions asking for free work, sometimes repeatedly to the same contributor. It is possible you will hit into an automatic question ban soon, so please change course if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you've had a chance to advance, this is how I'd solve it:

```
set fh [open filename r]
while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    if {[regexp {(.* TDO\s+: (\d+)'b)([01]+)\M} $line -> prefix len bits]} {
        set line [format "%s%0*s" $prefix $len $bits]
    }
    puts $line
}
close $fh
```

See:

- http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm
- http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/format.htm

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to give you code, because that's not really what Stack Overflow is for. But I'll talk you through how a programmer would think about this task.

Programming is all about breaking a task down into smaller tasks. So what do we need to do here?

- Read your input a line at a time (Where does it come from? Is is a file? Is it piped into your program so you read it from STDIN?)
- Recognise the lines that you need to investigate. How do you recognise lines that contain binary numbers?
- For lines that you don't need to process, write them unchanged to your output (is that a file?)
- For lines that you need to process, how do you break the data apart into tokens that you can investigate?
- How do you measure the length of a binary number?
- What is the correct length for a binary number?
- How do you pad a binary number to the correct length?

Think about the answers to these questions. If any question is too big to answer then think about breaking it down into smaller questions. Some of the questions you'll be able to answer by looking at the specification of your task. Some of them you'll need to get answers to by reading a programming language reference book.

Try stuff out. When you have code that does something (even if it doesn't solve every part of the problem) come back here and update your question to include your code. Explain what works and what you're having problems with. Ask us explicit questions. And we will try to help you.